# Best Way to Clean Up Cell Values in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm taking an RSS ('http://www.reddit.com/new/.rss?sort=new') and uploading it to a SQL database. Here are my steps:

From that URL I was able to create a pandas data frame which I will upload to a SQL database. The column names in the dataframe are title, link, summary, author and tags. What is the best way to clean up the summary column and get rid of all the tags??

```
'<!-- SC_OFF --><div class="md"><p>The title says most of it, I’m running about a 12-13 min mile. I haven’t run in about 4.5 years and I need to get to my fastest 1.5 with more in the tank afterward, and I need it to be solid. </p> <p>I’ve read blogs and running guides, but I thought I’d get it from the source, people who just love to run, just like the way I used to love to lift. </p> <p>I guess my question is, where do I start? Some say football conditioning, others say just run… Some even say just walk. I’m trying to slim down fast and have a solid mile and a half to 2-mile sprint. </p> <p>The only other conditioning I’m doing right now is three days of fight sports (2 Krav/kickboxing, 1 combat fitness style). Looking at running 3ish days and taking Sunday off.</p> </div><!-- SC_ON --> &#32; submitted by &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/user/Logical_penguin"> /u/Logical_penguin </a> &#32; to &#32; <a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/running/"> r/running </a> <br/> <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/running/comments/drt0nf/im_65_335lbs_ex_amature_strong_man_and_i_need_help/">[link]</a></span> &#32; <span><a href="https://www.reddit.com/r/running/comments/drt0nf/im_65_335lbs_ex_amature_strong_man_and_i_need_help/">[comments]</a></span>'
```

I was able to use the below for one portion

```
df['summary'] = df['summary'].map(lambda x: x.lstrip('<!-- SC_OFF --->'))
```

However this will take too long for everything in the summary column.

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
df['summary'] = df['summary'].map(lambda x: re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', x))
```

This can remove , result of your example will be:

*'The title says most of it, I’m running about a 12-13 min mile. I haven’t run in about 4.5 years and I need to get to my fastest 1.5 with more in the tank afterward, and I need it to be solid.  I’ve read blogs and running guides, but I thought I’d get it from the source, people who just love to run, just like the way I used to love to lift.  I guess my question is, where do I start? Some say football conditioning, others say just run… Some even say just walk. I’m trying to slim down fast and have a solid mile and a half to 2-mile sprint.  The only other conditioning I’m doing right now is three days of fight sports (2 Krav/kickboxing, 1 combat fitness style). Looking at running 3ish days and taking Sunday off.    submitted by    /u/Logical_penguin    to    r/running   [link]   [comments]'*

For single operations on the same example, performance of re and lstrip:
[image]

For a dataframe that has 10 rows(the same string):
[image]

re is more powerful than lstrip/rstrip in this scenario. Comparing them here is just to provide some info about how much time is taken away for re to perform.

Moreover, to save time, it is better to use re upon df.values instead of using apply/map.

Comment: Does `re.sub` work more faster than `.lstrip` ? can you provide with some time calculations too?

Comment: @Tserenjamts They are very different. lstrip and rstrip will not achieve your goal because there are tags in between. and regular expression is much powerful to match anything in tag format.

Comment: yeah i know i was asking you that how fast is `re.sub` :))